# Почему в цикле JS получаю не все атрибуты

Tags: javascript

Прохожу по коллекции элементов циклом forEach или FOR и почему то выводит только значение атрибута первого элемента а остальные null, хотя сами элементы выводит нормально

```js
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
var count = 0;
console.log(count);
document.querySelector('.next').onclick = function() {
  count++;
  sliders.forEach(function(i) {
    console.log(i.getAttribute('num'));
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="next">Click me</div>
<div class="slide" num="0"></div>
<div class="slide" num="1"></div>
<div class="slide" num="2"></div>
```

Comment: Он не проходил циклом, т.к. он не выполнял этой задачи.

Comment: Думаю ты не совсем понимаешь, что из себя представляет цикл... Для данной задачи лучше использовать  `if(){}`

Comment: И `count` вообще не из этой пьесы

Comment: возможно. это я пытаюсь самостоятельно написать свой слайдер, но затупляю, по задумке я при клике >>далее должен у текущего слайда сделать дисплей нон а у следующего показать. Ну однозначно я что то неправильно делаю так как первый раз=)

Comment: @Чайник, чтобы человек, к кому ты обратился в комментариях, получил уведомления, добавь в начале `@Имя`, я случайно заметил что ты ответил на коммент

Comment: В сниппете все выводится. Что нужно сделать, чтобы проблема воспроизвелась?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот наглядный пример, читай комментарии

```js
var gnext = document.getElementById('nextPicture');
var gprev = document.getElementById("prevPicture");
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

// первому элементу сразу задаем класс, чтобы он был виден
elem[0].classList.add('visible');

let count = 0;

function _count(direction) { // direction - это аргумент который определяет 
  // направления 
  // если нажимается кнопка следующий next 
  if (direction === '_next') {
    // и count равен длине массива elem-li (- 1)
    if (count == elem.length - 1)
      // count обнуляем
      count = 0;
    else
      // если count не равен длине массива elem-li (- 1)
      count++;

    // а тут проверяем обратное действие
  } else if (direction === '_prev') {
    if (count == 0)
      count = elem.length - 1;
    else
      count--;
  }

  // А вот тут уже цикл
  for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    // Чтобы у всех elem удалить класс visible
    elem[i].classList.remove('visible');
  }
  // А тут добавляем класс visible elem с нужным индексом 
  elem[count].classList.add('visible');
}

// ну а тут запускаем _count(direction) 
gnext.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // задавая направления  
  _count('_next');
})

gprev.addEventListener('click', function() {
  _count('_prev');
})
```

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <button id="prevPicture">Prev</button>
  <button id="nextPicture"> Next</button>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Slid1"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Slid2"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Slid3"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Slid4"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Slid5"></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Slid6"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: благодарю за помощь, это то что нужно, все проще дем я надумал=)

Answer (score 0):

Вот подправлено, но cout вам зачем?

```js
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
var count = 0;

function fn_count() {
  count++;
  sliders.forEach(function(i) {
    console.log(i.getAttribute('num'));
  });
};
```

```css
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="next" onclick="fn_count()">click</div>
<div class="slide" num="0"></div>
<div class="slide" num="1"></div>
<div class="slide" num="2"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, работает. count нужен чтобы сравнивать атрибут и выбирать следующий по номеру

Comment: В чем отличие данного кода от кода в вопросе? Учитывая, что поведение точно такое-же

Comment: Код в шапке был поправлен после вопроса.